# The datum provided is not an example of the schema

Tags: python, avro

I'm trying a sample code to write data in avro format. Below is the code :

```
from avro.io import DatumWriter, DatumReader, BinaryEncoder, BinaryDecoder
import avro.schema
from io import BytesIO

schema = avro.schema.parse("""
    {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "User",
        "namespace": "example.avro",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "Name",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
    }
""")

wb = BytesIO()
encoder = BinaryEncoder(wb)
writer = DatumWriter(schema)
writer.write('{"Id":"1", "name":"Khilesh"}', encoder)
```

However, I'm getting datum error -

```
avro.errors.AvroTypeException: The datum "{"Id":"1", "name":"Khilesh"}" provided for "User" is not an example of the schema {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "namespace": "example.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "name": "Id"
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "name": "Name"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm missing here, please help ?
I also tried, but no luck -

```
writer.write({"Id":"1", "name":"Khilesh"}, encoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

tried Below and it worked :

user.avsc :

```
{"namespace": "me.unittest",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "Id", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "Name",  "type": "string"}
 ]
}
```

Code :

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("user.avsc").read())

writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.append({"Id": "1", "Name": "Khilesh"})
writer.close()

reader = DataFileReader(open("users.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for user in reader:
    print(user)
    print('===================')
reader.close()
```